# Swift String and base64Encode Confusion

Tags: ios, swift, encode, swift5

I have problem with encoding data. My token has 1228 characters and

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: tokenString)!
```

works fine, but when i add to token some information and my token has 1263 characters `Data(base64Encoded:)` returns nil.

Problem in my opinion is in the string length or `Data(base64Encoded:)`.

Does `Data(base64Encoded:)` have any restrictions on the length of characters?
Please give me some info about this problem.

Comment: How do you "add some information" to the token? If you simply append another string to it it will likely not be a valid base64 string anymore, so `Data(base64Encoded:)` will return nil.

Comment: i use JWT token and add some data to PAYLOAD:DATA

Comment: Perhaps it'd help if you shared the code showing what the tokens are and what code you used to add data.

Comment: let data = Data(base64Encoded: "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyMTF9")! is work fine but

let data= Data(base64Encoded: "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyMX0")! return nil

Problem is in string length. base64Encode probably must multiple 4. Why?
Please tell me or link article about this problem

Comment: Yep, probably an encoding issue. Too much for a comment, so posted as an answer even though the question of where the encoding fails is still open :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you encode the modified token, but looks like the encoded Base64 string doesn't include [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) characters. Appending `=` to the modified token seems to fix the decoding issue:

```
// original token -> 57 bytes
let data1 = Data(base64Encoded: "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyMTF9")

// modified token -> nil
let data2 = Data(base64Encoded: "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyMX0")

// modified token with '=' for padding -> 56 bytes
let data2Fixed = Data(base64Encoded: "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyMX0=")

// decodes correctly: "{"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":15162390221}"
let string = String(data: data2Fixed!, encoding: .utf8)
```

So to solve it properly you probably need to look into the encoder. Hope that helps!

Comment: This solution does not seem elegant. Is there any other?

Comment: As mentioned, the best option would be to check how the token is encoded to Base64 and why the result doesn't include padding.